# Are there multi-headed trolls in Middle-earth beyond The Hobbit reference?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, trolls

I was just reading about Bilbo and the three trolls: William, Bert, and Tom.

At the end of the quote, there is a reference to multi-headed trolls.

> William choked. "Shut yer mouth!" he said as soon as he could. "Yer
> can't expect folks to stop here for ever just to be et by you and
> Bert. You've et a village and a half between yer, since we come down
> from the mountains. How much more d'yer want? And time's been up our
> way, when yer'd have said 'thank yer Bill' for a nice bit of o'fat
> valley mutton like what this is." He took a big bite off a sheep's leg
> he was toasting, and wiped his lips on his sleeve.
>
> Yes, I'm afraid trolls do behave like that, even those **with only one
> head each.**
> - *The Hobbit* p.35

Does Tolkien further describe multi-headed trolls in his notes, or is the reference just a *one-off* limited to *The Hobbit*?

Comment: Nice question. To my knowledge there is no creature with more than one head in the entire legendarium.

Comment: According to Douglas Anderson in "The Annotated Hobbit", they don't exist.

Comment: Also I don't remember any entry on Tolkien's Bestiary referencing multiheaded trolls... I'll try to check it.

Comment: @Bardo - Be very wary of referencing David Day. He's known to randomly make up facts in his books.

Comment: @ibid didn't know about that, do you have any reference I can check?

Comment: @Bardo - See [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/David_Day) and [here](http://tolkien.slimy.com/essays/DayBooks.html).

Comment: @ibid thanks, it's always good to get aware of this type of misreadings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"The Hobbit", when originally written, was simply a story for his children.  A lot of the book was written as if actually being told to the reader.  See the above quote: "Yes, I'm afraid trolls do behave like that..."

I have heard many stories as a child of giants, ogres, and trolls with multiple heads.  And usually they were defeated by the hero causing them to fight among themselves, much like Gandalf does in the book.

I don't think Tolkien meant to imply there were multi-headed trolls in Middle-earth, as much as to relate his story to other tales the reader might be familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

### Multi-headed trolls do not appear elsewhere in Tolkien's works, but they appear in other stories Tolkien would have been familiar with, most notably "Soria Moria Castle" from Andrew Lang's *The Red Fairy Book*.

In *The History of the Hobbit*, John Rateliff notes about this line (which in the original draft read "Yes I am afraid trolls behave like that, even those with one head only.")

> Trolls with multiple heads appear in many stories, perhaps the most famous of which is Dasent’s ‘Soria Moria Castle’, where the hero must confront and defeat first a three-headed troll, then a six-headed troll, and finally a nine-headed troll (*East o’ the Sun & West o’ the Moon* [1888], pages 397–401). This same story might have contributed to the naming of *Moria*; see Tolkien’s letter to Mr. Rang, August 1967; *Letters* p. 384.
> <sub>*The History of the Hobbit* - The Second Phase, II. Trolls</sub>

As Rateliff points out, Tolkien refers to this story as a possible source for the sound sequence he used when naming Moria.

> In fact [Moria] first appeared in The Hobbit chap. 1. It was there, as I remember, a casual ‘echo’ of Soria Moria Castle in one of the Scandinavian tales translated by Dasent. (The tale had no interest for me: I had already forgotten it and have never since looked at it. It was thus merely the source of the sound-sequence moria, which might have been found or composed elsewhere.) I liked the sound-sequence; it alliterated with ‘mines’, and it connected itself with the MOR element in my linguistic construction.
> <sub>Letter to Mr. Rang, August 1967, *The Letters of JRR Tolkien* #297</sub>

In *The Annotated Hobbit*, Douglas Anderson makes a similar observation, and also points out that this story along with an illustration of such a troll was included in one of Tolkien's favorite children's books.

> [image]
> Often in fairy stories, trolls are depicted as having many heads. The illustration above, by Lancelot Speed (1860-1931), is of the troll in the story
> “Soria Moria Castle” in The Red Fairy Book (1890), edited by Andrew Lang. The Red Fairy Book also contains one of Tolkien’s favorite childhood stories, that
> of Sigurd and the dragon Fafnir.
> <sub>*The Annotated Hobbit*</sub>

It is thus likely that Tolkien was trying to reference other fairy stories that his children would have been familiar with.